# Regex for EIN number and SSN number format in jquery

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

For jquery validation i need regex for SSN number format and EIN number format

EIN number like 52-4352452

SSN number like 555-55-5555

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For SSN's:

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=ssn

For EINs:

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1990

Comment: Since this is a top Google result, wanted to share the EIN regex includes prefixes that are not included in the IRS document it sources. Here is the same regex with updates:

`/^([0][1-6]|1[0-6]|(?!70)[27][0-7]|(?!31)[35][0-9]|[468][0-8]|9[0-589])?\d{7}$/`

Comment: As per IRS https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/how-eins-are-assigned-and-valid-ein-prefixes prefix 31 is used by SBA

Answer (score 13):

### Our Needs

- No prefix restrictions.
- [9-digit EIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number#EIN_format), hyphen optional.
- With the hyphen, acceptable format: `00-0000000`.

### Regular Expression

```
^\d{2}\-?\d{7}$
```

### Demonstrated with JavaScript/jQuery

```
<input type="text" id="ein1" value="0112345-67" />
<input type="text" id="ein2" value="01-1234567" />
<input type="text" id="ein3" value="011234567" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var patternEIN = /^\d{2}\-?\d{7}$/;

    patternEIN.test($('#ein1').val()); // fail
    patternEIN.test($('#ein2').val()); // pass
    patternEIN.test($('#ein3').val()); // pass
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For EINs, this will return `true` if it is valid:

```
/^(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)-\d{7}$/.test($('#your-ein-field-id').val())
```

To restrict it to actual prefixes, use this regular expression instead:

```
/^(0[1-6]||1[0-6]|2[0-7]|[35]\d|[468][0-8]|7[1-7]|9[0-58-9])-\d{7}$/
```

However, please note that if new prefixes are added this will not be up to date.

Answer (score 3):

As all previous answers treat this as two separate problems, I've combined the necessary regex into a single regex.

This will work for BOTH SSN and EIN, whether it's formatted with or without the use of hyphens.

`/(^\d{9})|(^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$)|(^[1-9]\d?-\d{7}$)/`